# Changing parameters on timers whilst game running

Tags: timer, coronasdk

How can I change a parameter on a timer when my app has already started?

Here is my function

```
increase = function()  
    frequency = frequency - 100
end
```

then I got a button that is supposed to increase the frequency of the timer

> object:addEventListener("tap", increase)

timer:

> frequency = 1000
>      superTimer = timer.performWithDelay(frequency, spawnCircle, -1)

Thanks! Joakim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
local freq = 1000;


 function increase()  
    freq = freq - 100
    print(freq)
 end


object:addEventListener("tap", increase)


function myTimer()
     superTimer = timer.performWithDelay(freq,function () spawnCircle();myTimer() end, 1)
end
myTimer()
```

This will be work.